# Is it possible to use patterns in $Assumptions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was trying to use patterns in $Assumptions as

```
$Assumptions = f[x_] > 0
Simplify[Sqrt[f[y]^2]]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

I want to define a class of assumptions thus is it possible to have something as above work? Thanks!

Comment: After doing some search, I found there are already a few threads about this question. Seems to me there is no perfect method yet, but we can add all needed rules before the calculation. See, [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15410/how-to-define-a-large-number-of-assumptions), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/pattern-matching-in-subscripted-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the Mathematica docs is `Sqrt[x^2]` and that it simplifies to Abs[x] if you supply the assumption `Element[x,Reals]`. This works well for function patterns as well:

`Simplify[Sqrt[f[x]^2], f[_] \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Worth noting this "direct" use of a patttern works because Element takes a pattern argument. You can not do for example f[_]>0 . See Jens answer here.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/pattern-matching-in-subscripted-variables